# Adaptive cross-browser CSS design based on FLEX. Why Chrome and Opera displays not correct?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox, adaptive-design

I created a simple adaptive html+css layout. Its meaning is that the inside of the main block with the content, the bottom has always been "nailed" footer, regardless of Page block content (content may be is empty!).
I realized design on css flex.If content block is empty, footer displayed correctly (stick to the bottom of the browser window) in Firefox, IE. 
But if i opening in Chrome or Opera, footer slides down out from browser windows (does not stick to the bottom of the browser window) about the height of the Header block

I can not find a reason, please tell me what is wrong with Chrome and Opera browsers.

p.s. Please **do not use absolute position**! This is reason for FLEX technology using.

p.p.s. Example code (Use "Full Page" snippet!):

```css
/*
 *   Main StyleSheets
 */

/* -- MAINBODY STYLES -- */
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flexColumnBlock, .flexRowBlock{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flexRowBlock{
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flexBlock{
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.pageBlock{
    /* Stylish */
    background-color: #67b168;
}


.flexHeader{
    /* Properties */
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
    /* Stylish */
    background: #269abc none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    height: 50px;
}


.flexSidebar{
    /* Properties */
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
    width: 250px;
    /* Stylish */
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background: #d58512;
}

.flexFooter{
    /* Properties */
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    /* Stylish */
    background-color: #23527c;
    border-top: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.flexMobileMenu{
    display: none;
}

/* -- DISPLAY RESOLUTION OPTIMIZATION -- */

/* -- Notebook screens -- */
@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
    .flexSidebar {
        display: none;
    }
    .flexMobileMenu{
        /* Properties */
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
        flex: 0 0 auto; 
        /* Stylish */
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        background: #d58512;
    }
    .flexBlock > .flexHeader {
        height: auto;
    }
    .flexFooter{
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .pageBlock{
        /* Stylish */
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
 <body>
        <div class="flexBlock flexRowBlock">
            <div class="flexBlock flexHeader">Header Block
            </div>
            <div class="flexBlock flexMobileMenu">Sidebar for mobile view</div>
            <div class="flexBlock flexColumnBlock">
                <div class="flexBlock flexSidebar">Sidebar block</div>
                <div class="flexBlock flexRowBlock">
                    <div class="flexBlock pageBlock">Page block</div>
                    <div class="flexBlock flexFooter">Footer block</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

p.p.p.s. Screenshots from Firefox (correct) and Chrome (not correct) is below

Firefox:
[Mozilla Firefox- screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N573s.png)

Chrome:
[Google Chrome - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFGV4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using flex requires a bit of new-thinking to get the results you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/bq37rtwy/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="flexheader">
    header
    </div>
    <div class="flexcontainer">
        <div class="flexsidenav">
        sidenav
        </div>
        <div class="flexcontent">
            <div class="maincontent">
            content
            </div>
            <div class="maincontentfooter">
            footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.flexheader {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexsidenav {
    width: 230px;
    background-color: gold;
}

.flexcontent {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

.maincontent {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.maincontentfooter {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Stian, thank you!
Your code is very good, but in Chrome still a problem.
If i open layout (with content exceeding the browser window height) in minimized Chrome, height for html and body elements is equal to current browser window, not layout.
Here: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4DfQNpNV2kEq/Image%20108.png
you can see red html/body backround behind the flexsidenav block. Flexsidenav here is equal to html/body elements.
Here my jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/o5813vq5/ (you need to save site on your workstantion and open in minimized Chrome for test).

Comment: If you want to use this as a fixed layout, you need to disable overflow on html and body, and enable it on the content box. If not, the whole body will scroll like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

problem come from the use of height and flex within childs .

```
.flexBlock{
    height: 100%;/* <=== HERE remove it!, it disturbs childs layout */
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}
```

use one or the other, **better use flex** than height, it will adapt size itself.*(see comments in style sheet )*

Only the main container needs to be sized, childs will follow flex properties

```
html, body, body>div { /* here add main container for 100% heights */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```css
/*
 *   Main StyleSheets
 */

/* -- MAINBODY STYLES -- */
html, body, body>div { /* here add main container for 100% heights */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flexColumnBlock, .flexRowBlock{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flexRowBlock{
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flexBlock{
    /* no need of size , flex is taking care of it */
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.pageBlock{
    /* Stylish */
    background-color: #67b168;
}


.flexHeader{
    /* Properties */
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
    /* Stylish */
    background: #269abc none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    height: 50px;
}


.flexSidebar{
    /* Properties */
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
    width: 250px;
    /* Stylish */
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background: #d58512;
}

.flexFooter{
    /* Properties */
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    /* Stylish */
    background-color: #23527c;
    border-top: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.flexMobileMenu{
    display: none;
}

/* -- DISPLAY RESOLUTION OPTIMIZATION -- */

/* -- Notebook screens -- */
@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
    .flexSidebar {
        display: none;
    }
    .flexMobileMenu{
        /* Properties */
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
        flex: 0 0 auto; 
        /* Stylish */
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        background: #d58512;
    }
    .flexBlock > .flexHeader {
        height: auto;
    }
    .flexFooter{
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    .pageBlock{
        /* Stylish */
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="flexBlock flexRowBlock">
            <div class="flexBlock flexHeader">Header Block
            </div>
            <div class="flexBlock flexMobileMenu">Sidebar for mobile view</div>
            <div class="flexBlock flexColumnBlock">
                <div class="flexBlock flexSidebar">Sidebar block</div>
                <div class="flexBlock flexRowBlock">
                    <div class="flexBlock pageBlock">Page block</div>
                    <div class="flexBlock flexFooter">Footer block</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

[image: screen in chrome W7]

works fine too in opera and my safari for windows, i spare you the screens shots ;)